Where is the following vedic verse found? ("Aham aryah adadat bhumim")

Aham aryah adadat bhumim

(I have given the earth to Aryans.)
It is often quoted in Arya samaj, but where is it found?

The line can be found in Rig Veda IV. 26, 2:

aham bhumim adadam āryāyāham vrshtim dāçushe martyāya

